# Display One Mesh On Top of Another

Tags: three.js

I have 2 3D models with roughly the same (pretty much the same) dimensions; both meshes will intersect and overlap at several points. I would like one mesh to always be displayed above the other and the mesh of the object underneath is never displayed unless it isn't covered by the mesh of the object on top--much like how a vest is worn over a shirt (vest is the mesh being displayed above). Without scaling, how can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `renderOrder` of your meshes and the `depthTest` property of the materials to `false`.

```
 material.depthTest = false;

 mesh1.renderOrder = 0;
 mesh2.renderOrder = 1;
```

Also have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2nuga2f/1/

and this three.js discourse thread: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/always-render-mesh-on-top-of-another/120

Comment: thank you. I got it to work by following the example you provided in the 2nd link. But it's still not 100%-- I believe it is another problem.